# Ionic2 RC4, doesn't find plugin in production mode

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic2

I am running Ionic 2 RC4 and when I run ionic run android the app works, but device ready is firing after 15-18 seconds. I tried to run on device ionic run android --prod, but it shows in chrome inspector that sqlite plugin is not installed which is not true. If I go to another page and come back it shows my data from SQLite.

```
constructor is called
main.js:1 Native: tried accessing the SQLite plugin but it's not installed.
x @ main.js:1
main.js:1 Install the SQLite plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage'
x @ main.js:1
cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
main.js:4 Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
(anonymous) @ main.js:4
main.js:4 DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 2684 ms
error getting scheduled matches TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined
at _ (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at main.js:1
at new t (polyfills.js:3)
at e (main.js:1)
at s (main.js:1)
at t.<anonymous> (main.js:1)
at t.value [as executeSql] (main.js:1)
at t.getScheduledMatches (main.js:9)
at t.getMatchInfo (main.js:23)
```

I tried to place device ready in several different locations and I also logged in many places. The last console log that is called is called constructor

```
constructor(public timeSince: TimeSinceService,
    public platform: Platform) { 
    console.log("constructor is called"); //called

    if(!this.isOpen){            
        this.db = new SQLite();
        this.db.openDatabase({name: "aces.db", location: "default"}).then(() => {
            console.log("open Database"); // not called

            this.db.executeSql('PRAGMA user_version = 0', []).then(()=>console.log("yesss")) // not called
            this.db.executeSql('PRAGMA user_version', []).then(data => {
                if(data.rows.item(0).user_version !== current_version){
                console.log("versions do not match");
                }
            })

            this.db.executeSql('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', []).then(()=>{
                let query_matches = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS matches '+ 
                                '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+
                                ...';
                let query_comments = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments '+ 
                            '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '+
                            ...';
                let query_points = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undo'+ 
                            '(point_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+ 
                            ...';
                let query_organizations = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS organizations '...
                let query_users = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users '+ 
                            '(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,'+
                            ...';
                Promise.all([      
                    this.db.executeSql(query_matches, {}).then(() => {
                        console.log("table created");
                    }, (err) => console.error('Unable to execute sql for matches: ', err)),
                    this.db.executeSql(query_comments, {}).then(() => {
                        console.log("comment table created");
                    }, (err) => console.error('Unable to execute sql for create comment table: ', err)),
                    this.db.executeSql(query_organizations, {}).then(() => {
                    console.log("table organizations created");
                    }, (err) => console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err)),
                    this.db.executeSql(query_points, {}).then(() => {
                        console.log("undo table created");
                    }, (err) => console.error('Unable to execute sql for undo table: ', err)),
                    this.db.executeSql(query_users, {}).then(() => {
                        console.log("table users created");
                        }, (err) => console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err))
                ]).then(()=> {
                    console.log("called promise all");
                    this.isOpen = true
                })
            })
        }, (error) => console.log("ERROR couldn't open database from sqlite service: ", error));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case somebody runs into the same problem.

I had to call rootPage inside DeviceReady inside my app.component.ts. I hope it helps to somebody.

Comment: I am having same issues with the deviceready not fired. What do you mean by "call rootPage" ?

Comment: Instead of giving a value when you declare variable rootPage = TabsPage just declare variable rootPage; and then in device ready give value to rootPage.

Comment: I was having the same issue and you saved my day. Thanks a lot.